# Swapping from pirated to licenced Office - licencing issues

Tags: microsoft-office, license, legal, piracy

I was using a pirated Office for a while. I have since deleted it, bought one from Microsoft, downloaded it from their website, and installed it. For a while it worked OK, but after a day or two, I started getting "there's a problem with your office license" pop-ups. Using `cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus` gives the following information about my license (there's only one):

```
LICENSE NAME: Office 16, Office16ProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition

LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 16, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel

BETA EXPIRATION: 01/01/1601

LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED---

ERROR CODE: 0x4004F040 (for information purposes only as the status is licensed)

ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product was activated but the owner should verify the Product Use Rights.

REMAINING GRACE: xxx days  (xxxxxx minute(s) before expiring)

Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX

Activation Type Configuration: ALL
```

Reinstalling doesn't help. Is that somehow caused by the fact I used to have a pirated Office installed? Maybe I had both of them installed at the same time at one point. At this point, I'm not sure.

Can I fix it in a legitimate way? And can I get in trouble for having had my Microsoft Account (linked to my personal information) logged in to a cracked Office?

Comment: Sure it can be fixed. By reinstalling Windows.

Comment: I always thought KMS activation was for corporate servers, and that direct-from-Microsoft would have a different licensing channel (going off memory since I use open office). If MS retail now uses KMS, then this error is known to occur when a client sees TWO KMS servers. Either way, it looks like removing the old version of office left the (hack) activation in place.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I guess I'll try that. Can I get in trouble though for having been logged in with my Microsoft Account into this new office with an old crack still in place, or for having been logged in into the old, cracked one? Can Microsoft even tell it took place?